# Unclear restrictions on properties when instantiating metaClass: Class

Tags: meta-object-facility

In section 9.3.3 (Constraints) of the MOF 2.5.1 specification the following conditions are listed in order to instantiate a metaClass: Class:

[4] Property: 0 <= LowerBound <= UpperBound required.
[5] Property: 1 <= UpperBound required.
[9] Property: Container end must not have upperBound >1, a property can only be contained in one container.

I dont understand what is meant by [4] and [5], and with [9] ChatGPT gave me below example:

```
class Department {
  attribute name: String;
  reference employees: Employee[*];  -- employees are contained in the Department
}

class Employee {
  attribute name: String;
  reference department: Department;  -- reference to the container (Department)
}

The employees reference in the Department class represents the container end. It has an upper bound * (unbounded), indicating that a department can contain multiple employees, and this adheres to the constraint “Container end must not have upperBound >1.” Here, the upper bound is not greater than 1; it is unbounded, allowing for any number of employees.
```

In this age of alternate facts this should make sense, but I’m from the time before so can someone please logically explain what is meant by [4],[5] and [9]?